# How do i rewrite these math python functions in ruby?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, math

Python

`order = log(max(abs(s), 1), 10)`

This is what i have so far, but the 'max' thing is whats confusing me.

`order = Math.log10(s.abs)`

And this one too

`sign = 1 if s > 0 else -1 if s < 0 else 0`

I'm not quite sure where to start on this one as I dont understand python syntax

Comment: I removed you tag. What has this question to do with Mathematica?

Comment: In Python, you could wirte `sign` as `(s > 0) - (s < 0)`.  Maybe this also works in Ruby.

Comment: @Sven No, that is `true-false` or somesuch - even those are objects.

Comment: @steenslag: In Python, `True` and `False` are objects as well, but you can subtract them anyway.  (Integers are, of course, also objects.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first you want [Math.log](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Math.html#method-c-log) and [Enumerable#max](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max).

```
Math.log [s.abs, 1].max, 10
Math.log10 [s.abs, 1].max  # or use Math.log10 and skip passing the base
```

For the later, there are several ways to express it. Use `if` as an expression, use ternary operator `test ? ifval : elsval`, or most succintly, the "spaceship" comparator `<=>`

```
sign = if s > 0 then 1 elsif s < 0 then -1 else 0 end
sign = s > 0 ? 1 : s < 0 ? -1 : 0
sign = s <=> 0
```

Answer (score 4):

For the first:

```
Math.log10([s.abs, 1].max, 10)
```

For the second:

```
sign = s > 0 ? 1 : s < 0 ? -1 : 0
```

I think I got that right heh. Basically, arrays have a `.max` method, so use that. And you an use ternary statements in the form:

```
boolean_expression ? val_if_true : val_if_false
```

Comment: I assume you dont mean ,10 for the log10?

Answer (score 1):

`max(abs(s), 1)` returns `abs(s)` or `1`, whichever is greater.

---

```
sign = 1 if s > 0 else -1 if s < 0 else 0
```

can be rewritten as

```
if s > 0:
    sign = 1 
elif s < 0:
    sign = -1
else:
    sign = 0
```